# Javascript location.host without www

Tags: javascript

I have a php file which is been used to share posts of my users on Facebook and Twitter. If I click on the Twitter icon for example, I get a screen where the hyperlink to my site is automatically been written. This is good, but I like to remove the `www.` part of the url that is automatically shown on the Twitter screen. I guess this has something to do with location.host, so I googled, but I couldn't find a proper answer to this problem.

Here is an example of my code:

```
function e(f,i,an)
{
        with(document)
        {
                write('<div style="width:100%"><table id=m'+i+' style="visibility:hidden"><tr>');
                write('<td id="vst' + i + '" style="white-space:nowrap">&nbsp;</td>');
                write('<td hr(this.childNodes[0])" title="share on facebook"><a href="javascript:od(\'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + location.host + '/e/'+ i +'\',900,400)" class=icon><img src="images/facebook.png" target="_blank"></a></td>');
        write('<td hr(this.childNodes[0])" title="share on twitter"><a href="javascript:od(\'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + location.host + '/e/'+ i +' - %20read!\',800,600)" class=icon><img src="images/twitter.png" target="_blank"></a></td>');
                write('<td class=ei><a name="cid'+i+'"></a><a href="e/'+i+'">( #'+i+' )</a></td>'); 

                  document.write('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
```

My second question would be this: how can I add a custom title on the Twitter screen: for example, my websitename without having to use location.host together with the title of the TOPICNAME that is being shared?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For your first... you could modify the host:

```
location.host.replace('www.','')
```

---

**Edit: address concerns**

Having been down-voted again, and seeing lots of up-votes on the first comment, I will attempt to address concern about subdomains besides `www` that contain `www`...

Still steering clear of regex for this solution, mostly because generally it is harder to maintain regex, and there are a lot of developers who just don't touch regex at all...

```
var cleaned_host;
if(location.host.indexOf('www.') === 0){
    cleaned_host = location.host.replace('www.','');
}
// do something with `cleaned_host`
```

... or more succinctly ...

```
location.host.indexOf('www.') && location.host || location.host.replace('www.', '');
// evaluates to hostname with starting `www.` removed
```

Comment: Could even make that `location.host.replace(/^www\./,'')` so that `www.` is only removed from the _beginning_ of the hostname.  But that's unlikely to make any difference unless your hostname happens to be something like [`no-www.org`](http://no-www.org/).

Comment: -1 It happens, I've seen domains like wwww.domain.tld (with 4 w's). Also, the domain itself could end with www, like www.thisismywww.org, in which case this messes things up.

Comment: I stick by my answer, which uses string replacement, which is more efficient than regex. Don't get me wrong, I wish regex could be extended to be turing complete, but it is not always as good as string functions. If the guy was writing a library that was to be used in many unknown situations, I might think about using regex, or string replacement on the first characters only, but I doubt that is necessary in this case.

Comment: Good answer @BillyMoon

Comment: I've submitted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401664/4829915) that handles that above comments plus keeps the spirit of @BillyMoon's no regex when it can be avoided.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to get only the second- and top-level-domains, not any subdomains, this should help you:

```
var url = location.host; // e.g. "www.example.com"
return url.split(".").slice(-2).join("."); // "example.com"
```

This also works for other subdomains and even for more-than-threeleveldomains.

Answer (score 2):

location.host.replace('http://www.','')

or (if you want to keep the http://)

location.host.replace('http://www.','http://')

It makes sure you only replace www if it is at the beginning.

Comment: -1: `location.host` contains only the hostname part of the URL. It does not include the scheme, so your `.replace()` will never match.

Comment: Thank you GolezTrol. Now, my last question remains. I hope someone can help me out with that.

Answer (score 0):

## Remove all various www. matches

---

If you need to remove **www.** or **w.** or **ww.** or **ww2.** and so on, code below might become handy.

#### Javascript

```
var searchPattern = "^w+\\d*\\." ;
var rx = new RegExp( searchPattern, "gim" ) ;
var replacePattern = "" ;
var replacedText = sourceText.replace( rx, replacePattern ) ;
```

#### PHP

```
preg_replace( '|(?mi-Us)^w+\\d*\\.|D', '', $sourceText, $limit, $count) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543794/4829915) insists on not using regex, which means it doesn't cover certain situations as described in comments.

But here's a regex-free solution that should cover everything. I've also used `hostname` over `host`:

```js
function thedomain(domain) {
  var subdomain = 'www.', subdomain_len = subdomain.length;
  if (domain.substr(subdomain, subdomain_len) == subdomain)
    domain = domain.substring(subdomain_len)
  return domain;
}
console.log(thedomain(location.hostname)); // Strips www if needed
console.log(thedomain('www.foobar.com')); // Strips www      
console.log(thedomain('wwww.foobar.com')); // Does NOT strip www
console.log(thedomain('prefix.www.foobar.com')); // Does NOT strip www
```