# How to show the domain name without www but to work even if the user enters domain.com (without www)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the `domain.com` from `www.domain.com` or `www.domain.com/fdfds/fsdfd.php` or `domain.com`

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
var subdomain = parts.shift();
var upperleveldomain = parts.join('.');
alert(upperleveldomain);
```

However it is working if the domain has www. but it does not working without www. It gives me only `com`

How to fix this? Any different suggestions?

Comment: The subpath isnt part of your domain-name. The path after it are either Apache path variables or GET parameters (after `?`). You need to get those separately from your domain-name.

Comment: OP doesn't care about the query string, they're just trying to get domain.com - so while that's true, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `parts.shift();` in all cases, which removes the first element of the array. You only want that first element removed if it contains the string `www`, so you just need to check that condition and `shift()` only if the www is present.

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
if(parts[0] === "www") {
    parts.shift();
}
var upperleveldomain = parts.join('.');
alert(upperleveldomain);
```

You could likely also solve this problem with a regular expression, if you were so inclined - but you've come up with a pretty simple way to do it that should be one tweak away from working.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I found a lot of regex, none of them are working... I think this is quite simple thing and it drives me crazy

Comment: Indeed - the first paragraph of my answer should fix your issue. You just need to check if the first item in your array is "www" and if not, don't do the .split().

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos - did this answer work for you? It would be helpful if you accept whichever answer helps you fix your problem, as that's how good answers are marked for future visitors!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Billy Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665261/billy-moon) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543794/167088) just replace the 'www' part of the hostname with an empty string and you are (presumably) closer to what you want:

```
var strLocation = location.host.replace('www.','');
alert(strLocation);
```

The issue is, that you are splitting your domain name into an array by the period character and then throwing away the first part of that array. That means the hostname part if the URL is `example.org` and the www part if the URL is `www.example.org`.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be (editing your code):

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');

if(parts[0].localeCompare("www") == 0)
    var subdomain = parts.shift();

var upperleveldomain = parts.join('.');

alert(upperleveldomain);
```

Or you can just replace www. with an empty string:

```
var newHostname = location.hostname.replace("www.","");
alert(newHostname);
```